# Ubuntu Upgrade, Perl Version Broke ZImbra

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, zimbra

Kind of in a bind here, since I heard about the bash bugs last night I decided on upgrading all off my server, not just the packages but the complete OS, it worked fine on all my servers, except my mail server, which was running Ubuntu 12.04 and I upgrade to 14.04. Everything seem running correctly but when I try to get the Zimbra service running I get the Following:

> Perl API version v5.14.0 of Socket does not match v5.18.0 at
>   /usr/share/perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 92. Compilation failed in
>   require at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Sys/Syslog.pm line 10. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Sys/Syslog.pm line
>   10. Compilation failed in require at /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Zimbra/Mon/Logger.pm line 21. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Zimbra/Mon/Logger.pm line 21. Compilation
>   failed in require at /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol line 27. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol line 27.

I was kind of guessing it was problems with my Perl Version, So I downloaded perlbrew, but when I try to change the version from 5.18.0 to 5.14.0 I get the following:

> Perl API version v5.14.0 of List::Util does not match v5.18.0 at
>   /usr/share/perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 92. Compilation failed in
>   require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/App/perlbrew.pm line 22. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/App/perlbrew.pm line 22. Compilation
>   failed in require at /usr/local/bin/perlbrew line 6. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/perlbrew line 6.

Quite the large bind for me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) will be a better place for this question.

Comment: Or maybe http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Zimbra you are currently using?

You need to upgrade Zimbra to version 8.5.x which supports Ubuntu 14.04. Zimbra 8.0.x and below does not support Ubuntu 14.04.

Edit: Zimbra 8.0.8 now supports Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: zmcontrol -v
Perl API version v5.14.0 of Socket does not match v5.18.0 at /usr/share/perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 92.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Sys/Syslog.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Sys/Syslog.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Zimbra/Mon/Logger.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Zimbra/Mon/Logger.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol line 27.